# Flask Setup Code. UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pwmOneDutyCycle' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi

I am trying to setup GPIO ports on a flask server to give it input remotely.

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_first_request():
def before_first_request():
   GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
   pwmOne = GPIO.PWM(12, 100)
   pwmOneDutyCycle = 0
   pwmOne.start(pwmOneDutyCycle)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def remoteInput():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      ...
      pwmOneDutyCycle += 10
      pwmOne.ChangeDutyCycle(pwmOneDutyCycle)
....
```

Whenever it receives a request it says the pwmOneDutyCycle is not defined (i'm assuming pwmOne is not defined either). Why? Any tips for how I can fix this? I need to initialize this code once and don't want it to reinitialize upon each individual request.

Comment: This error persists when I try to use the global keyword

```
global pwmOneDutyCycle
pwmOneDutyCycle = 0
```

Comment: The `global` statement must be in `remoteInput` as well, since it is assigning a new object.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm confused. What is ```remoteInput```?

Comment: It looks like what you are trying to achieve is having a global "thing" that you initialize once and that you can use in different views. This sounds pretty much like the thing that you would do when connecting to a database (open connection in a central place and execute your SQL all over the views). Maybe you can apply the practices over here to your problem: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/tutorial/database/
Oh and before_first_request is deprecated: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/changes/

Comment: Do you not see the function called `remoteInput` in your code?

Comment: @TimRoberts No it is almost exactly as seen in the post

Comment: Yes.  LOOK at the code in the post.  Line 15 is `def remoteInput():`.  Is this not really your code?  Did you not write this?

Comment: Oh geez I'm sorry. The method names did not line up between my code.

I understand now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to have `pwmOneDutyCycle` outside of the 2 functions - `before_first_request`, `remoteInput`
2. Then you need to make it global in each of the 2 functions

   In the end, you should have something like this

   ```
   pwmOneDutyCycle = None

   def before_first_request():
      global pwmOneDutyCycle

   def remoteInput():
      global pwmOneDutyCycle
   ```
3. Explanation

   a) When your file loads, it initializes the variable `pwmOneDutyCycle` to a value of None

   b) Then before the first request is sent, it updates that value to 0

   c) Finally in remoteInput, it increases the value by 10